# ui-sref not generating working href

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I'm new to Angular and I've been struggling all day to get ngRoute to work without any success. So I decided to try out the ui-router but that's not working for me either.
(angularjs 1.5.0)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title>My app</title>
    <script src="js/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <a ui-sref="state1">State hello</a>
    <a ui-sref="state2">State show</a>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
{
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");

  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "partials/hello.html"
    })
    .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      templateUrl: "partials/show.html"
    });
});
```

hello.html & show.html

```
<div>{{"hello"}}</div>
```

When loading index.html I get this error:

```
angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error%3A%2…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using wrong module name.

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
```

Change your module name to "MyApp" in your js file. i.e.

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router']);
```

Comment: To piggyback on this, it's good to use one naming convention and stick to it. I use camelCase for my projects.

Comment: And it sucks knowing that the issue that you have been struggling with whole day was too simple. Happens to me all the time learning new stuff. lol
I use camelCase too :)

@Mangs can you mark this as accepted?

Comment: I actually had a struggle with ngRoute, but when this also caused a problem I had to go here. Yes I will, but SO doesn't allow that for another 6 minutes.